# How to tell how close we are to a GC for java processes?

Tags: java, statistics, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I'm currently implementing some revisions in my ongoing project and I'm curious about their potential impact on garbage collection metrics. Specifically, I'm interested in continuing a custom paradigm for the project, that is, avoiding any GC activity during a specific timeframe within the program's execution. To achieve this, I'd like to gauge whether the new code modifications bring me closer to a potential garbage collection occurrence during a specific time period. Are there any helpful tools available for this purpose? Any suggestions on specific statistics I should be tracking or monitoring?

In my initial attempts to address this challenge, I implemented logging mechanisms to capture memory data in both the young and old generations after each garbage collection cycle. This approach proved relatively straightforward to implement in Java using the available methods. However, I have doubts regarding the adequacy of this approach since the process consistently avoids initiating garbage collection during the specific timeframe of interest. Consequently, the collected statistics reflect historical data from a period preceding the targeted timeframe and fail to provide any insights into the current proximity to a potential garbage collection event.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible at all, but which GC algorithm are you using? How is it configured? Did you consider using a non GC language? Why you want to avoid GC? I suspect this is an XY Problem. You should probably ask about the original problem you are trying to resolve.

Comment: This seems like an attempt to predict the future.

Comment: “avoiding any GC activity during a specific timeframe within the program's execution” would require a non-concurrent GC as otherwise the garbage collector may be already running at the start of the timeframe. Then, you would have to avoid *all* allocations within that timeframe as even the tiniest allocation may trigger a GC and, well, stop the operating system, to prevent all potential external triggers.

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to give more information about the project, but won't it suffice to have the system continually log the memory occupied by both the young and old generations, and then just check if with the new code, it trends towards occupying more memory in the heap? If there was any significant change, then it would be detectable using the logged stats? I might be totally wrong here though since I am still a beginner. Is there even a way to log memory occupied in old/young generations?

Comment: Java by design shields the programmer from memory management. You can hack your way to get the information you are asking, but still probably fail to achieve your objective. You should rethink the approach in terms of your objectives. Tell us why are you trying to avoid GC.

Comment: By design, Java is not built to let you tinker with the memory management. If you have to, for whatever reason, Java is the wrong language. For some cases it might be sufficient to go with some kind of real time java https://www.rtsj.org/

Comment: It seems you are assuming that a piece of code will always allocate the same amount of memory, so running it a single time and record the memory allocations will tell you something. That’s debunkable with trivial examples, how much memory will `new byte[someVariable]` allocate? And what about `for(int i = 0; i < otherVariable; i++) list.add(new Object());`? (Even if you know `otherVariable`, you have to know the actual list type to predict what `add` may allocate internally (which may also depend on the initial capacity the list had before the code). And `HashMap.put` depends on the hashcode…

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you want to avoid GC pauses/latency in a specific timeframe? If so, you might be more successful by actually tuning/switching to a different GC (e.g. ZGC).